# Avoiding boilerplate code when handling events (Backbone, CoffeeScript)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, refactoring, coffeescript

Consider the following example http://jsfiddle.net/YmWW2/.

How can I avoid redundant methods like `execFoo`, `execBar`, `execBaz` and pass string like `"foo"` directly to `exec` method?

```
events:
    "click a#foo" : "execFoo"
    "click a#bar" : "execBar"
    "click a#baz" : "execBaz"

execFoo: -> @exec "foo"
execBar: -> @exec "bar"
execBaz: -> @exec "baz"

exec: (x) -> alert x
```

Comment: Are you asking how you can bind your methods to parameters instead of defining an anonymous method, if that's the case check out the 'bind' method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you can get the 'foo', 'bar' information by examining the [event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) that jquery passes to click handlers.

For example, the following snippet should alert the id attribute of any link that gets clicked.

```
events:
  'click a' : 'exec'

exec: (event) ->
  clickedLink = $(event.target)
  alert(clickedLink.id())
```

Comment: Or just `alert event.target.id`. jQuery is a bit overkill for this purpose.

Comment: I actually think instead of event.target, event.currentTarget needs to be used to get the anchor element, since Backbone does the actual event-binding as `@$el.on eventName, selector, listenerFunction` (paraphrased).